# How can I direct an RFID reader to only read in a specific direction?

Tags: rf, radio, rfid

I'm trying to control the reading direction of an RFID reader, to only read in a specific direction.

I made a drawing to exemplify my question.

In the image you can see the setup I want to have. The difference between the two, is that image to limit the reading area of the RFID. The question is how this would be possible to do?

[image]

[image]

Any input to my question is welcome, since I'm not experienced with RFID technology.

The solution I want to achieve, is the one in image 2, where I limit the reader to not include nearby tags.

Comment: By using the word "beam" there I am really not sure if you understand how all this works...

Comment: Call it radio frequency :-)

Comment: With an directional antenna.

Comment: That makes sense. Can I control the antennas spread of the radio frequency as showed in the images?

Comment: What frequency band do your tags use? What are the dimensions in your drawing? I'm guessing that the objects are moving past the reader on a conveyor belt -- can you simply increase the object spacing on the belt?

Comment: @TommyOtzen please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask this question is kind of broad, meaning there could be many answers. This site requires questions that are not broad.

Comment: Is the RFID system far-field or near-field based?  If it is near-field is it inductive or capacitive coupled?  Knowing the RFID protocol would answer this question.

Comment: @DakotaD Neither far-field or near-field is decided. Which would be the one to chose, to solve the problem?

Comment: @TommyOtzen The choice between near-field and far-field depends upon many factors, perhaps the most important being distance between interrogator and tag.  If you can place them very close together, on the order of centimeters, near-field is probably preferred for your application.  It has intrinsically less field-of-view than far-field, so reading adjacent tags shouldn't be a problem as long as the distance between the interrogator and the desired tag is significantly less than the distance between the interrogator and adjacent tags.

Comment: The distance will be between 1 and 2 cm. So I think you just answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can place metal strips between the unwanted RFID tags (NoTags) and the reader that still leave a path to your tag of interest (YesTag). This will reduce the RFID reader field strength but it will work perfectly well if the distance from reader to YesTag is short enough and the shields are far back enough. These don't need to be grounded.

Your diagram doesn't show any distances though so I can't say either way. If you've got the set-up you've drawn, you can find out quick enough, obviously.

Last year I did quite a lot of experimenting with RFID tags and readers as we were mounting it amongst a lot of steel. Incidentally, our reader could detect and identify multiple tags within its field but that's probably not helping what you're trying to do.

(Incidentally, 'beam' is a harmless enough word, we all know perfectly well what you mean :-) )

Comment: Your answer seems good, but not aplicable in our case, since the tags are not fixed and not on a fixed surface.

Comment: @TommyOtzen, sure, no problem. Can you describe where they are and what they're doing?